# Issue with redirecting with returnUrl when path contains query string

Tags: angularjs

I have the following authorization interceptor which redirects the user to my login route when a 401 occurs:

```
app.factory('authHttpResponseInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                console.log("Response 401");
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401 && $location.path() !== '/') {
                $location.path('/login').search('returnUrl', $location.path());
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}]);
```

I want it to set the URL the user attempted to visit as the returnURL.  Unfortunately, if the URL is something like `/join?code123&id=456` it redirects to `/login?code123&id=456&returnUrl=%2Flogin`.  As you can see, it's keeping the query string that enters the interceptor in the query string rather than including it in the `returnUrl`.

I then thought to use `$location.url()` in the redirect like this:

```
$location.path('/login').search('returnUrl', $location.url());
```

... which does indeed put the full query string in the `returnUrl`, but the query string remains in the path like this: `/login?code123&id=456&returnUrl=%2Flogin%3Fcode%3D123%26id%3D456`.  AFAIK, to remove items from the query string you have to manually clear them out (eg. `$location.path().search('code', null)`) which is just not right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this in a slightly different way.

I got rid of the returnUrl code such that my interceptor's responseError looks like this:

```
responseError: function (rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401 && $location.path() !== '/') {
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

I then added the following:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
        $rootScope.previousPage = absOldUrl;
    });
}]);
```

Then my code that handles redirecting post-login looks like this:

```
var login = function (credentials) {
    return $http.post('/api/login', credentials).then(function (response) {
        var previousUrl = urlParserFilter($rootScope.previousPage);
        var path = previousUrl.hash.substr(1);
        if (path !== '/login') {
            $location.path(path);
        }
        else {
            $location.path('/');
        }
    });
};
```

This, unfortunately, still doesn't handle query strings properly, but it does handle redirecting and I reworked the only area of my site that includes query strings into a different URL structure.  I ended up using the [urlParser](https://github.com/xemle/angular-url-parser) library to help.